# Passing parameters to a function in hashmap value

Tags: java, java-8

I am having a scenario where I am calling a function present in hashmap value as follows,

```
  Map<Character, IntSupplier> commands = new HashMap<>();

            // Populate commands map
           int number=10;
            commands.put('h', () -> funtion1(number) );
            commands.put('t', () -> funtion1(number) );

            // Invoke some command
            char cmd = 'h';
          IntSupplier result=  commands.get(cmd); //How can I pass a parameter over here?

System.out.println(" Return value is "+result.getAsInt());
```

My question is that can I pass the parameter to the function (function1) when getting the hashmap value i.e. when using commands.get(cmd).

Thank you.

Comment: What does `function1` look like (what is its signature)? Is it an `int function1(int i) { ... }`?

Comment: It is a simple function which takes an integer as a parameter.                 
 like-    static int funtion1(int num)

Comment: You can surely, but in this case you would have to use an [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) instead of an [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [a `Map<Character, IntUnaryOperator>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html):

```
Map<Character, IntUnaryOperator> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put('h', number -> funtion1(number) );
commands.put('t', number -> funtion1(number) );

// Invoke some command
char cmd = 'h';
IntUnaryOperator result=  commands.get(cmd);
```

Now you can pass an `int` parameter to the operator:

```
System.out.println(" Return value is " + result.applyAsInt(10));
```

Comment: Thank you @assylias. Can you please tell what to do with the number.                          It is giving me error as" Lambda expression's parameter number cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope. "

Comment: @user7749322 because you already have a `number` variable declared somewhere. Just change `number` to `i` in my example or remove the number variable from your code.

Comment: How can I alter the program to return an string? Or what to do for getting a different return value.

Comment: To return a String, you would need a `IntFunction<String>` and function1 would need to look like `String function1(int i) { return "a string"; }`.